# Fresh react native EXPO app is not working

Tags: react-native

I just create a react native app using the following command:

```
expo init first-react-native
```

And try run this app using

```
expo start
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
```

N.B: I am novice to react native and struggling to resolve this issues but no luck. Any idea?

Comment: I think doc said you could also use `npm start`, see if it has the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

This is caused by node `v12.11.0` due to the way it deals regular location.
You can try one of these solutions to resolve this.

### Solution 1

Try installing the latest version of Node or you can downgrade to node `v12.10.0` this will apply the correct way to deal with parsing error

### Solution 2

You can correctly terminate the regular expression in your case by changing the file located in:

```sh
\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js
```

**From:**

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

**To:**

```
 var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Hope this Helps!